# How do I connect a female EEG electrode to a breadboard?

Tags: circuit-design, analog, signal-processing, instrumentation-amplifier, eeg

Electrode output end:

[image]

EEG electrode:

[image]

I'm trying to connect the output of EEG electrodes to a breadboard as input. How do I connect the electrode to the breadboard? Usual jumper wires don't seem to fit and adding normal wires and soldering them isn't possible.

Comment: what is usually used to connect the cable?

Comment: Isn't that just a banana jack?

Comment: https://electrodestore.com/blogs/news/touch-proof-electrode-connectors

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 you're right! I thought I read EKG rather than EEG in the original post. I will edit my answer and incorporate yours.

Answer (score 4):

The connector for EEG electrodes is the DIN 42802, which comes in 1.5 mm (DIN 42802-1) and 2.0 mm (DIN 42802-2) versions. Try to measure the inside diameter of your electrode connectors to sort this out.

The use of a female/socket rather than a plug on the electrode cable is for patient safety, to avoid the risk of a disconnected plug dragging across some metal object. The male/plug for DIN 42802 also is "touch proofed" with a hollow plastic shroud that the pin is recessed into.

The DIN 42802 connector itself isn't easily obtained, but you can buy "EEG Electrode Extension Wires" with a plug on one end and a socket on the other. Just cut off the socket/female end, strip and tin the wire end, and insert it in your breadboard. You could crimp on a Dupont connector instead if you have the contacts and tooling.

If instead you are using EKG electrodes (can't be absolutely sure from the photo) then you just need a standard banana plug which is 4 mm diameter and has springs that bulge outward slightly to make firm contact with the female/socket. In this case just obtain some banana jumper cables with a male on each end, cut them in half, strip and tin the cut ends, and insert into your breadboard.

Comment: Thanks for responding! If i can't get a proper extension wire, can I simply cut the electrode female end and solder a wire and extend it? Will this cause any issues or problems? (Like issues in signal transmission?)

Comment: @Mayur Yes, you should be able to cut the female connector off the electrode wire and solder a wire to extend it -- unless it's "tinsel wire" (google that) which is challenging to solder. For your extension use a stranded, small diameter wire (22 ga down to 30 ga) so it's flexible.